# is it possible to integrate my custom logging system to google adsence ad tag

Tags: google-search-console

i have a custom logging system,

my client provide me a script of google adsence ad tag

(which using domain http://adserver.adtech.de/addyn/ with ad tag id and other staff )

and i want to track how many clicks on this ad tag

So  i need to integrate my custom logging system to google adsence,

by using some parameter like in double click or other 3 rd party media company

is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think you would be better of using the Adsense API to retrieve this information http://code.google.com/apis/adsense/management/v1/reference.html#collection_reports

I don't know what success you'll have trying to intercept the click event on the ads.  Even if you could get it to work (which is unlikely as it's rendered from a different domain) Google would likely ban you for tampering with the ads